# Handle raised exceptions with http.post().subcribe()

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a backend API to login.
It will raise 401 Unauthorized if password is not correct.

My question is, how to handle raised exceptions in angular.

```js
this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:3101/users/login',{username:"admin",password:"admin"}).subscribe({ 
  error: (respose:any) => { 
    debugger
    // not catch backend exceptions !!!  such 401 Unauthorized 
    // it will work only for front end exceptions such 
   },    // errorHandler 
   next: (respose:any) => {  
     debugger
   },     // nextHandler
   // someOtherProperty: 42
});
```

for example :

```py
INFO:     127.0.0.1:58809 - "POST /users/login HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

debugger of next: (respose:any) => {  ... will fire ...

```py
INFO:     127.0.0.1:59091 - "POST /users/login HTTP/1.1" 401 Unauthorized
```

I want debugger error: (respose:any) => {  fire ...  **But it does not work :(**

I want to catch backend exceptions in frontend.

Comment: Maybe you have an HTTP Interceptor (https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) that handles the error. `this.http.post(...)` returns an observable that has gone through every registered HTTP Interceptor, so some of them may catch errors and not let them through to your `.subscribe({error: () => ...})`.

Comment: @NicolasB 
sorry I didnt found how to use HTTP Interceptor

could you create simple example to use HTTP Interceptor with post API ...

Answer (score 0):

you can handle it with `catchErorr` rxjs operator:
for example:

```
 this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:3101/users/login',{username:"admin",password:"admin"}).pipe(
  catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    if (error.status === 401) {
      // handle the 401 error
      // for example, redirect the user to the login page
    }
    return throwError(error);
  })
```

you should know the best place to handle it, it's in `Http Interceptor` for example:

```
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
     Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
       return next.handle(req).pipe(
         catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
           if (error.status === 401) {

           }
            return throwError(error);
          })
         );
        }
      }
```